# iloc method return different type of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataset 30 obs and 2 columns i used code below to create independent and depend dataset for a single linear regression.

So each dataset is expected to be a 1 column array.

But the return X is a 2d arrary and returned y is a 1d array what is the reason for that?

So to put my quetion in one line:

what is the difference between

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
```

and

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values?
```

When I use:

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

X.shape
Out[207]: (30,)
y.shape
Out[204]: (30,)
```

When I use:

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

X.shape
Out[203]: (30, 1)
y.shape
Out[204]: (30,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:-1` represents a range<sup>1</sup>, while `-1` is a scalar. Ranges are 1-dimensional, while scalars are 0-dimensional. Think of a line versus a point; a range is a line while a scalar is a point. This is reflected in how Pandas translates a range vs scalar when indexing.

Therefore, the following are equivalent for a dataframe with 2 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5, 2)))

df.iloc[:, :-1].shape  # (5, 1)
df.iloc[:, [0]].shape  # (5, 1)
```

Using a scalar will remove the extra dimension. You can do this in a couple of ways:

```
df.iloc[:, 0].shape   # (5,)
df.iloc[:, -2].shape  # (5,)
```

---

In fact, `:-1` is syntactic sugar for a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object: `slice(0, -1)`. In practice, the simpler syntax is preferred unless you need to pass `slice` objects around.

Comment: thx! I am new to python. I m a little crazy about how difficult it is to me. this helps so much!

Answer (score 0):

The output of the iloc function is series return type for 1-d array and a 2-d array for a matrix.That's why in your case,when you give the index for y (its is 1-d array),it returns a series and for the rest of the dataset,it return a 2-d array.